# Strange network socket leak in Java app

Tags: java, sockets, networking, memory-leaks

I'm trying to catch a network socket leak in our Java daemon, which has quite a strange output in lsof:

```
java    11734 root  463u  IPv6          225927527                TCP 192.168.254.1:http->192.168.254.1:46149 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    11734 root  464u  IPv6          225927347                TCP 192.168.254.1:http->192.168.254.1:46102 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    11734 root  465u  IPv6          225928791                TCP 192.168.254.1:http->192.168.254.1:46451 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    11734 root  466u  IPv6          225927617                TCP 192.168.254.1:http->192.168.254.1:46170 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    11734 root  467u  IPv6          225930330                TCP 192.168.254.1:http->192.168.254.1:57333 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

And so on, until it eats all the available descriptors and leads to "Too many files" error.

Any idea what can cause this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CLOSE_WAIT means a passive close, i.e. the server received FIN from the client, but nothing else happened. You can check how the client-side closes the sockets. It seems to be `shutdown` call without closing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: We do have a mechanism that self-tests if the ports are open, and I thought the leak is there, but after a double-check, it seems to close the sockets correctly.

Comment: Are you ever actually closing your client sockets?

Comment: You appear to be closing connections, perhaps you could look at ways to keep the connection longer so it doesn't leave closed sockets waiting to timeout.

Comment: @khachik: the client is sending a FIN, whether via close or shutdown doesn't really matter. The problem is at the server end - it is not closing.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: he doesn't appear to be closing connections at all.

Comment: @EJP, I see. I assume you are saying that the other end is closing connections which he is retaining.

Comment: Indeed, we missed the closing in finally, which means on any exceptions (such as produced by client sending FIN), the sockets were left open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CLOSE_WAIT` means that the connection has been closed by the remote peer but the socket is waiting for the local application to close it. So you're not doing that.

You need to check that you handle EOS properly, i.e. by closing the socket, under all circumstances where it can arise, and ditto `IOExceptions` on any socket operation - you must respond to *all* of them except `SocketTimeoutException` by closing the socket. You must also ensure sockets are closed in `finally` blocks.

Comment: Final block was the ticket, it appears while my client side sockets closed normally, the server side (part of same self-monitoring) were left open until caught by GC.

Comment: @naXa `EOFException` is an EOS, but not all EOS's are `EOFExceptions`. If I had meant `EOFException` I would have written it.